# javascript replace() function strange behaviour with regexp

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Am i doing sth wrong or there is a problem with JS replace ?

```
<input type="text" id="a" value="(55) 55-55-55" />​

document.write($("#a").val().replace(/()-/g,''));​

prints (55) 555555
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Yb2yV/

how can i replace () and spaces too?

Comment: `replace(/[\(\)\040-]/g,''));` Replace with () and spaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a JavaScript regular expression, the `(` and `)` characters have special meaning. If you want to list them literally, put a backslash (`\`) in front of them.

If your goal is to get rid of all the `(`, `)`, `-`, and space characters, you could do it with a character class combined with an alternation (e.g., either-or) on `\s`, which stands for "white**s**pace":

```
document.write($("#a").val().replace(/[()\-]|\s/g,''));​
```

(I didn't put backslashes in front of the `()` because you don't need to within a character class. I did put one in front of the `-` because within a character class, `-` has special meaning.)

Alternately, if you want to get rid of ***anything*** that isn't a digit, you can use `\D`:

```
document.write($("#a").val().replace(/\D/g,''));​
```

`\D` means "not a digit" (note that it's a capital, `\d` in lower case is the opposite [any digit]).

More info on the [MDN page on regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a character class

```
/[-() ]/
```

Using `"-"` as the first character solves the ambiguity because a dash is normally used for ranges (e.g. `[a-zA-Z0-9]`).

Answer (score 0):

```
document.write($("#a").val().replace(/[\s()-]/g,''));​
```

That will remove all whitespace (\s), parens, and dashes

Answer (score 0):

The brackets indicate a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) in the regexp. You'd need to escape them (`/\(\)-/`) to match the sequence "()-". Yet I guess you want to use a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), i.e. a expression that matches "(", ")" or "-"; for whitespaces include the [`\s` shorthand](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html):

```
value.replace(/[()-\s]/g, "");
```

You might want to read some [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) or [tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
.replace(/\(|\)|-| /g,'')
```

You have to escape the parenthesis (i.e. `\(` instead of `(`). In your regexp, you want to list the four items: `\(`, `\)`, '-' and  (space) and as you want to replace **any** of them, not just a string of them four together, you have to use OR `|` between them.

Answer (score 0):

You want to match any character in the set, so you should use square brackets to make a character set:

```
document.write($("#a").val().replace(/[()\- ]/g,''));
```

Normally, parentheses have a [special meaning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_Parentheses) in regular expressions, so they were being ignored in your regex, leaving just the dash.  Normally, to get literal parentheses, you need to escape them with `\` (but in a square bracket block, as above, you don't).

The dash above is escaped because it has normally indicates range in a character set, e.g., `[a-z]`.

Answer (score 0):

May be very bad but a very basic approach would be,

```
document.write($("#a").val().replace(/(\()|(\))|-| |/g,''));​​
```

`|` means `OR`,
`\` is used for escaping reserved symbols